# Cannot enable Additional drivers for Broadcom in 12.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, 12.10, broadcom

tl;dr version: Additional Drivers does not work for enabling a driver in Ubuntu 12.10, however it worked in 12.04.

---

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04 via a live USB. I did a fresh install to avoid any conflicts. From 12.04 I know that my wireless card has proprietary drivers that could be installed via Additional Drivers. I did eventually find additional drivers in the software sources menu, however when I attempt to switch to Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source, it not only does not work, it in fact disables my wireless completely. The only way to revert this is to restart, and revert back to "do not use the device". Then upon another restart, my wireless will function once again. I was curious if anyone else had this issue, and if there was a fix for it as of yet. I looked on launchpad and it may be a potential bug, but I am unsure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (and sorry for that wall of text). Until then, I'll continue to use my wireless as it is (or revert to 12.04), but I do notice a slower connection without it enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work for me=> 
[check this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218986/how-to-fix-a-broadcom-43224-rev-01-in-ubuntu-12-10-running-on-a-macbook-pro), i hope that resolve your problem

Please run:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

Is your pci.id 14e4:4353? If so,please do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

If your pci.id is different, please post it and we'll recommend a fix.

Comment: Your answer is excellent my friend. I had gotten a new laptop (System76 ftw) to replace my old laptop since it was outdated anyways so I had paid little attention. But when I saw that answer, I booted up that other laptop (since it works fine, just 3 years old) and the stupid linux headers must have been corrupted in some way or another.

Comment: Any way to do this without internet access? As my laptop wifi doesn't work at all (it worked during live cd, very easy to enable just set it on Additional Drivers even without internet) and no ethernet access. Also no matter how I enabled these additional drivers, they get disabled again immediately, no error message at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing 12.04 and 12.10 on a friend's Dell netbook.
I installed Linux Mint instead and managed to get it working.
Installed 12.10 again this morning and had to go into Software Sources again and re-install the broadcom driver from there - although it was selected when asked on pr-install setup.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install it by installing the broadcom-sta-common first and then install that driver . Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to:

- [Recompile kernel](https://askubuntu.com/q/119080/65926)
- Then install driver from [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=62666)

It works perfectly for me.

[More information](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145884).