# How to fix a Broadcom 43224 (rev. 01) in ubuntu 12.10, running on a macbook pro 6,2?

Tags: wireless, 12.10, broadcom, macbook

I've googled for 3 days so far, with no success, so I'll be straightforward:

How do you get it to work?

this is the output for `lspci -v`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 0093
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at c1b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

for `uname -a`:

```
Linux fury 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried with `bcmwl-kernel-source`, `firmware-b43-installer` and now I'm out of ideas. Can someone help me? This is driving me insane!

EDIT:

for `lspci -nn | grep 0280`:

```
 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
```

I can see the networks available, but when I try to connect, it gets stuck in a loop: tries to connect, fails, tries again, fails again and so on...

EDIT 2:

After a long break from this problem, I've just run a few tests again and found out that, although my macbuntu still fails to connect to my home wi-fi network, it works just fine at my university... Does that help in anyway? My home network is managed by a dual-band (2.4Ghz and 5Ghz) 802.11n cisco e4200 wi-fi router.

EDIT 3 (4 months and a bunch of updates later):

So, now it's working. I did nothing, really, except for updating the packages as suggested by Ubunutu. Now I'm using modules wl and bcma on kernel 3.5.0-26-generic.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, except I can't see the networks at all (my network manager indicator says "No network devices available"). My pci.id is exactly the same.

Comment: the terminal says me b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05) What could i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please run:

```
    lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

Is your pci.id 14e4:4353? If so,please do:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
    sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

If your pci.id is different, please post it and we'll recommend a fix.

Comment: Yeah, that's the exact pci.id for my wlan device... But now, although it shows the networks available, I'm stuck in a loop (I was before already): it tries to connect, fails, tries again and so on...

Comment: Please make sure no competing drivers are loaded: lsmod | grep -e ndis -e b43 -e brcm. If any are loaded, we may need to blacklist. Did you try a reboot?

Comment: So, after a long break from this problem, I've just run a few tests again and found out that, although my macbuntu still fails to connect to my home wi-fi network, it works just fine at my university... Does that help in anyway? My home network is managed by a dual-band (2.4Ghz and 5Ghz) 802.11n cisco e4200 wi-fi router.

Comment: If you reset the router to G only, no N, is there any improvement?

Comment: So, I just checked that there are no competing modules installed (through `lsmod | grep -e ndis -e b43 -e brcm`), I've set the wireless router to G-only with 20Mhz-only channel width, and all this to no avail. As the university network is open, I even disabled password protection on my router, and still no improvement... Why does hardware support in linux have to be such a pain?

Comment: Any luck on resolving this, @EduardoBezerra?

Comment: @Wescrock I've given up. Apparently, it has something to do with my cisco e4200 router. It works everywhere else. The weird thing is that every other device (even another linux box with a different wireless chipset) connects flawlessly to this router.

Comment: Is there any improvement if you change the encryption on your router to WPA2 only, not mixed mode WPA and WPA2? If you change channels? If you turn off N speeds?

Comment: I have the same chipset (in my Macbook Air). I also have intermittent issues with some networks/access points. I have had more luck with the `brcmsmac` driver -- it's somewhat unreliable in that the connection drops in weird ways, usually when the signal is a little low, but it works better than the `bcmwl` driver.