# Ubuntu 12.10 on Macbook Pro 5,5 (Wifi Issue)

Tags: 12.10, wireless, xubuntu, broadcom, macbook

I know this question gets asked almost every day with a different Macbook version, but I can't seem to find anything definitive for a Summer '09 MBP (5,5).

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and wifi won't work. I am VERY new to Ubuntu, so I need some guidance as to HOW to troubleshoot this.

On a side note, I have followed several other guides and I have verified that there are some Broadcom drivers installed, but I'm not sure if they are the right ones.

So, I suppose my two questions are as follows:

1) What steps would you take to begin resolving this issue of missing wireless

2) Is it possible that, if I installed xUbuntu (I like its GUI more), I wouldn't have this same issue?

Thank you, in advance,
Wes

---

My wireless adapter is:

BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci` so we can figure out what Broadcom you have?

Comment: OK. unfortunately, I am at work now and left that laptop at home. I will run this tonight. That said, doing a search, think I have the following: Broadcom 4322AG 802.11a/b/g/draft-n Wi-Fi Adapter

Comment: Looks to BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue, once knowing my broadcom model.

Here is a [link.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218986/how-to-fix-a-broadcom-43224-rev-01-in-ubuntu-12-10-running-on-a-macbook-pro)